# Add a border to a white DIV added to the DOM after page load with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using this jQuery library on a project **Simple Color Picker**
https://github.com/tkrotoff/jquery-simplecolorpicker

It converts a dropdown selection field into clickable squares with the background of them being the color choice.

[image]

The code it generates for a square looks like this...

```
<span class="color" title="White" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" data-color="#FFFFFF" role="button" tabindex="0"></span>
```

My problem is I need to add a dark border color for the `White` color option as you cannot see it on a white page!

The code above is for the white color option that is generated and inserted into the DOM.

I do not know how I can target this color choice after it is added to the DOM and add a border, any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I just saw this code in the JavaScript library that generates the output for each color...

```
 var $colorSpan = $('<span class="color"'
                     + title
                     + ' style="background-color: ' + color + ';"'
                     + ' data-color="' + color + '"'
                     + selected
                     + disabled
                     + role + '>'
                     + '</span>');
```

So it looks like I can try adding a color class name to each item and then targeting the CSS class for the white option!

Comment: what about looking to see what css classes are applied?

Comment: You could do some hacky css like `.color[title=White] { border: black; }`

Comment: @DanielA.White That was my first option but no specific class is applied.  I am now looking at the JS library that generates the code and it looks like I could easily make it add a class with the color name!

Comment: @Matthew I was wondering if something like that was possible!  THat would prevent me from editing the JS library at least

Comment: I think you can, you may run into issues with really old browsers, if you're able to change the plugin then that is the better option.  If it's an open-source project perhaps consider making a contribution to it to add that functionality.

Comment: @Matthew: even ie7 supports it.

Comment: Matthew beat me to it... here would be an example at least:
http://jsfiddle.net/ua5vpnu7/

Comment: Using the example above, you can also use the pseudo-class last-child to style the white: http://jsfiddle.net/ua5vpnu7/4/

Comment: @MatthewMy main reason for wanting to avoid changing the JS library code was to make it easier to upgrade it if never needed to.  You suggestion to push my modifications to the Library and see if the owner will integrate is a great idea though, one I hadn't thought of so thanks for that too!  For right now I ended up using your CSS selector method until I can change the library code.  If you would like to post an answer with your CSS selector & suggestion to submit library changes to the project owner, I can select your answer. Otherwise I will delete this question as it has no answers! Thanks